# Why do we need to override methods — Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I'm new to Objective-C and I did a big step from web developing (php) to ios developing.

Why should I override and implement methods from the superclass? 
Don't these methods already exist in their superclass?

For example,  I have a table view controller. Why isn't a property like: numbers of rows,  Instead of implementing a method? 
And why don't we implement all the methods that exist in the superclass?

I guess I have a lack of knowledge in all of the inheritance system in Objective-C.

Comment: The concept of overriding methods is not specific to Objective-C. All OO programming languages support this feature.

Comment: All classed-based OOP languages. In prototype-based languages, copying and replacing is the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method overriding, in object oriented programming, is a language feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent classes. The implementation in the subclass overrides (replaces) the implementation in the superclass by providing a method that has same name, same parameters or signature, and same return type as the method in the parent class. The version of a method that is executed will be determined by the object that is used to invoke it. If an object of a parent class is used to invoke the method, then the version in the parent class will be executed, but if an object of the subclass is used to invoke the method, then the version in the child class will be executed. 
This is a very powerfull aspect of the object oriented programing. 
Exemple:
C subclass B and B subclass A

They all have the same methode print
If you have an Arrays with one instance name arr
For i in arr { 
Print (i)
}
The good methode print 'll be call for each object

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about overriding methods but the example you gave with the tableView is not overriding the methods.  The tableView is using the delegate pattern.  In the delegate pattern, there is a protocol that is defined.  Let's use UITableView as the example:

The protocol that is defined is the UITableviewDataSource.  This is basically a declaration that methods like numberOfRowsInSection should exist in whichever class conforms to this protocol.

When you tell the tableView that you conform to its UITableViewDataSource protocol by saying tableview.dataSource = self, you are telling it that you implement the methods listed in the UITableviewDataSource declaration.

This pattern creates an api for the tableView to consume without having knowledge of the class providing it.  Essentially, the tableview will be asking your class for information via the UITableviewDataSource api that was defined.

You can do a search on the delegate pattern to find the pros and cons of implementing it.

Comment: Thanks, what is an api? And what if i don't want to use table view data saurce protocol, should i implement those methods too?

Comment: These questions can be answered with a simple Google search.